# Can I have spaces in Cucumber/SpecFlow Tags

Tags: visual-studio, cucumber, specflow

I am using SpecFlow to write some tests with Visual Studio 2015 and SpecFlow 1.9.

Is it possible to have a tag on a scenario that includes spaces in the SpecFlow feature file?

```
Feature: My Feature
Some info

@I really want spaces here
Scenario: My Scenario
        ...
```

The above produces an error:

```
Custom tool error: Parsing error near '@I really want spaces here'
```

I haven't come across anything in the Cucumber [docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags).

I've tried guessing various usages to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can have spaces in your tags, and it seems that using `-` would be the preferred option

Comment: Hmm, was afraid so.  Just looking at a consistent way of naming the Traits that show up in the Test Explorer.  I had some MSTests in there with spaces in.  I guess I shall rename these.

Comment: But if you are using NUnit - it doesn't like dashes in the Test Category name or value.

Comment: could you use underscores? sounds like there isn't going to be a nice solution for this as the unit test providers are specific, so we would need to do something specific based on unit test provider

Comment: Trouble is that we are using different unit test providers - ala Microsoft and NUnit.  I was trying to find a consistent way to name Categories that appear in the Test Tools window.  Ideally we are better off sticking to a single provider, but this is the way things have panned out.  I am going to use a ".".  It works but it's a bit close to namespace hierarchy convention.